# LibreOffice Write - insert>formula missing symbols

Tags: libreoffice, plasma

I have this issue with LO writer where inserting a formula is displayed with gibberish as such:
[Formula issue with missing icons/symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h241T.png)

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with SDDM for kubuntu plasma. 
The LO is up to date as v6.4. 
I did install MS office fonts.

After searching for a solution with no solution, I come here just before wiping my system again and trying to pinpoint the problem.

Edit, Feb 21st 2020:
As for @K7AAY's request:

```
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.44.0
Qt Version: 5.9.5
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: Did you change the desktop environment from Ubuntu 18.04's standard GNOME3 to KDE Plasma, right? Which version of KDE Plasma is in use? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.